# javascript get length of results in if clauses

Tags: javascript

I want to get the length of results in if clauses where it is true and then write it in the input hidden element.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
  var imgs = document.getElementById("images").getElementsByTagName("img");
  var imgSrcs = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
         $('#loaderimg').html(imgSrcs += getImgSize(imgs[i].src));
  }

  function getImgSize(imgSrc){
      var newImg = new Image();
      newImg.src = imgSrc;
      var height = newImg.height;
      var width = newImg.width;
      p = $(newImg).ready(function(){
          return {width: newImg.width, height: newImg.height};
      });
      // return (p[0]['width']+" "+p[0]['height']);
      if(p[0]['width'] >= 100){
         return ('<img src="'+imgSrc+'" id="'+i+'" width="100" style="max-height:150px;">');
      }else{
        return ('');
      }
  } 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: We need more info. What is p[0]?

Comment: It's a variable previously defined

Comment: Yes but what is in the variable?

Comment: Wonderful case of developer trying to make asynchronous code act like synchronous.

Comment: You cannot do this, `ready()` is an asynchronous call. You may have to set a timer to get the `size` of the image.

Comment: Where are you using the function `getImgSize()`?

Comment: Complete code is posted...

Comment: Is it possible to get the results length in the if clause?

Comment: Looking at the code, you should just wait til window.onload was fired, and loop through and get the values.

Comment: `.ready` is a special method which listens to the DOM being completely loaded. You have to bind an event handler to the `load` event of the image and work with callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this version. Note that this may not be exactly working code, you can get an idea how to do this.

What is done is, the `img` is added when the `ready()` fires.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i;
    var total_images = 0;

    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var imgs = document.getElementById("images").getElementsByTagName("img");
        var imgSrcs = [];

        for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            getImgSize(imgs[i].src);
        }

        function getImgSize(imgSrc){
            var newImg = new Image();
            newImg.src = imgSrc;
            var height = newImg.height;
            var width = newImg.width;

            p = $(newImg).ready(function(){
                if(newImg.width >= 100){
                    $('#loaderimg').html($('#loaderimg').html() + '<img src="' + imgSrc + '" id="' + i + '" width="100" style="max-height:150px;">');
                    $('#total_images').val(total_images);
                    total_images++;
                }
            });
        } 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: I want to write the number of total img in this input <input type="hidden" name="total_images" id="total_images" value="" />

Comment: looks good your code, not working but this is a good idea...so I check your answer as answered...